# How many foreign keys can a table have in postgreSQL?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

I am working on a Django project with a database in PostgreSQL. During my schema design, I have noticed that one table is referencing many foreign keys from other tables. Just curious that how many foreign keys can be referenced from/to one table? I also searched and found that the **SQL server 2014** can reference up to253 foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a hard limit. I just created a table with 10001 foreign key constraints.

Of course that doesn't mean that it is sane to define that many foreign keys, and performance will suffer considerably.